# Javascript user must enter 6-character code

Tags: javascript, string

So, I need the user to enter a 6-character registration number. The prompt, should repeat if the user does not enter a 6-character code or presses cancel. For context, The prompts ask the user more about their vehicle and 5 other vehicles, and then displays the information in a table.

```
vehicle.registration = prompt("Please enter a 6-character vehicle registration number");
        if (value.length <6) {
            vehicle.registration = prompt("That is not a valid response. Please enter a 6-character registration number");
            continue;
            else {
                document.getElementById("registration" + i).innerHTML = vehicle.registration;
        }
```

I've tried `Value.length`, `string.length`.. I'm not sure why it isn't working.

Comment: Where is your end-brace for the if-condition?

Comment: you never initialized a variable called `value`, only an object called `vehicle` with `registration` as property, so `if (vehicle.registration.length == 6)`

Comment: I'm pretty sure that code would result in syntax errors. Have you checked the console?

Comment: What's the point of `prompt`ing users here? How about just 6 inputs?

Comment: I think you should close the braces properly and you have to check vehicle.registration.length to check the length.

Comment: @CalvinNunes  I tried vehicle.registration.length and it still does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to access or store the value of the prompt window i.e. `vehicle.registration`.

Also, you can place the validation logic in a while-loop to ask until valid input is received.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt

```js
const promptMessage = 'Please enter a 6-character vehicle registration number',
      maxRegistrationLength = 6;

let vehicle = {}; // Reference scope

// The initial request
vehicle.registration = prompt(promptMessage);

// Keep validating until true
while (vehicle.registration.length < maxRegistrationLength) {
  // Ask again...
  vehicle.registration = prompt('That is not a valid response. ' + promptMessage);
}

// Display the valid input
document.getElementById('registration').innerHTML = vehicle.registration;
```

```html
<p>Registration #<span id="registration"></span></p>
```

Comment: this works as a snippet but does not work in my code.

Comment: @BreeSergent Be specific, *"Does not work in my code"* doesn't help much... what happens? There is errors in the console log? Did you posted all code that is relevant to this function/question? What exactly happen?